# Source of drushayate anen iti darshanam,

Tags: identification-request

Darshanam/Darshana has this basic well known definition,

"drushyatainenitidarshanam", word-meaning, by which (sat and asat are visible), where is the source of it?

I think it is not from nighantu, where is it from then?